# C# bot, that can instantly buy released item

Tags: c#, bots, windows-forms-designer

is it even possible to make a bot in C# (windows forms), that would work like when Supreme release new items, the bot would instantly buy them? If anyone has any ideas please share them, thanks!

Comment: Sorry, but that isn't really anything we can help you with at SO. SO deals with concrete problems, not with giving out links to potential tools

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is - yes, it surely is possible.

First of all you have to think about logging in on the site
Afterwards you have to have a link on where these drops appear and pass it to the code
Finally you need to just implement a  automatic checkout system.

It will require a bit of work and time to do it.
There are already some projects made for this kind of websites.

You can check this link: https://github.com/jg-fisher/supreme-bot
It has an automatic checkout (providing personal details in the checkout form).

Also some bigger project of chrome extension - https://github.com/Paulowarren31/Supreme-Bot

I advise you to get suggestions from there and build your own program.